# ConfigParser pyodc generating error' Invalid - user name (12) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python, configparser

Sorry, I am a newbie in Python and trying to work on the ConfigParser module. I am trying to connect netezza to python via config file.I am getting error invalid user which is not correct since i have verified user id and password . The conn mentioned in below format works fine if i use it directly in the script rather than using the ConfigParser module

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER= 
       {NetezzaSQL};SERVER=netezzadev02.xxx.com; 
       PORT=5460;DATABASE=EDWxx; 
       UID=anxxx;PWD=kkkkk;")
```

But when i use configparser,ini file and start creating below code i get error' pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', u'[08001] Invalid - user name (12) (SQLDriverConnect)')' .
I am explaining my code below.
---Creating ini file first

```
import pyodbc                                                    
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['NETEZZA'] = {'DRIVER': 'NetezzaSQL',
                    'SERVER': 'netezzadev02.xxx.com',
                    'DATABASE': 'EDWxx',
                    'PORT': '5460',
                    'UID': 'anxxx',
                    'PWD': 'kkkkk;',
}
with open('db_connect.ini', 'w') as configfile:
config.write(configfile)
```

Adding ini file in Main Python script to load netezza logging credentials.

```
import configparser
print('\nEstablishing DB Connection..........')
config = configparser.ConfigParser()    
config.read('db_connect.ini')
constr = 'DRIVER={{{drv}}};SERVER={srv};DATABASE= 
                 {db};PORT={prt},UID={uid},PWD={pwd};'\
                  .format(drv=config['NETEZZA'['DRIVER'],
                  srv=config['NETEZZA']['SERVER'],
                  db=config['NETEZZA']['DATABASE'],
                  prt=config['NETEZZA']['PORT'],
                  uid=config['NETEZZA']['UID'],
                  pwd=config['NETEZZA']['PWD'])
conn = pyodbc.connect(constr)
```

Please help me to resolve this error or point out what mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the built-in get(section, option) function of configparser, as I am not sure the way you have it implemented will work.

So, rather than `config['NETEZZA'['DRIVER']` do `config.get('NETEZZA','DRIVER')`

Also, I don't know if you realized it, but you were are missing a ']' here `drv=config['NETEZZA'`

Answer (score 0):

I realise this might be a bit late, but if anyone encounters this error again: it's just about the formatting of the string that's passed to pyodbc's `connect` function. In my case, there were some extra spaces there which messed things up. In your case, it's because there are commas between `PORT`, `UID` and `PWD` instead of semicolons.